# Why do I get incomplete type when using forward declaration instead of #include?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, incomplete-type

Here I have state_machine.h:

```
#ifndef STATE_MACHINE_H
#define STATE_MACHINE_H

// state machine classes

//#include "state_t.h"
class state_t;

class state_machine
{

public:
    state_machine();
    void change_state(state_t *newState);
    void process_state(int data);

private:
    state_t *_state;
};

#endif // STATE_MACHINE_H
```

And here is state_t.h:

```
#ifndef STATE_T_H
#define STATE_T_H

#include <QByteArray>
#include <QDebug>

//#include "state_machine.h"
class state_machine;

class state_t
{
public:
    state_t(QByteArray stateName);
    virtual ~state_t();
    virtual void processState(state_machine *sm, int input) = 0;

    void defaultUnknownEventHandler(int event);

    QByteArray name;
};

#endif // STATE_T_H
```

Then some state classes, which are all the same more or less, I'll just list one:

teststate1.h:

```
#ifndef TESTSTATE1_H
#define TESTSTATE1_H

#include "state_t.h"

class testState1 : public state_t
{
public:
    testState1();
    void processState(state_machine *sm, int event);
};

#endif // TESTSTATE1_H
```

teststate.cpp:

```
#include "teststate1.h"
#include "teststate2.h"

testState1::testState1() :
    state_t("state1")
{
}

void testState1::processState(state_machine *sm, int event)
{
    qDebug() << name << ": event" << event;
    switch (event)
    {
        case 2:
        {
            // error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class state_machine'
            sm->change_state(new testState2()); 
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            defaultUnknownEventHandler(event);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem:**

I am trying to tidy up my code and use the minimal amount of header inclusion (especially in header files) by using forward declarations. You can see in the state_machine class header I have commented out `#include "state_t.h"` and replaced it with a forward declaration `class state_t;`. This worked and my code compiled and ran.

Then, in state.h I replaced `#include "state_machine.h"` with a forward declaration `class state_machine;` (you can see where I commented it out).

But now I get the error `error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class state_machine'` which I have commented in testState1.cpp code. But I am not sure why. Why is state_machine an incomplete type?

Comment: Put the include where it is needed: in `teststate.cpp`.

Comment: There must be tons of duplicates for this question, I just can't find the right one.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks, plesae see my comment to Mike below... I am also not sure why this is required : (

Comment: @rubenvb yes, I have beedn going through some of them, but I can't quite "align" them with my code. As a result of what I was reading I am trying to use forward decs...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`teststate.cpp` needs the definition of `state_machine`; so include `state_machine.h` there.

"Incomplete" means that the compiler has only seen a declaration, `class state_machine;`, not a full definition. You can do various things with an incomplete type, such as declaring pointers or references. But you can't call member functions (as you do here), or more generally do anything that requires knowledge of the class members, without the full definition.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand why that is... it includes teststate1.h which includes state_t.h which has the forward declaration of state_machine, so why did that not work? and why is it an incomplete type? ... this confuses me!

Comment: @code_fodder: It's incomplete because it's been declared but not defined. You need full definition (from the header) to call a member function.

Comment: ahh, even when its a pointer?, its the actual member-call that is requiring it to be implicitly defined?, ok, I think I see. Thanks!

Comment: @code_fodder: The member call requires knowledge of the members, which are only available from the full definition.

Comment: thanks very much!, I just did not fully understand that part of it :)